# Process and Clipboard Data

Tags: visual-studio, clipboard

I want to know is their any way through which we can determine process id of process where clipboard data going to paste.
Thank you.

Comment: What language are you using for this?

Comment: You might want to look into using something like [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx), [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx), or [GetProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683215(v=vs.85).aspx)... more information [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/12137/).

Comment: thank you sir for reply. Can you please tell me how can I monitor paste event continuously so that when particular window matchs with required window and then I can check content of clipboard.